# JPA Nested Select Left Outer Join

Tags: java, jpa, toplink

Is it possible to do a nested select in JPA QL?

How would I write the following SQL statement in JPA QL?

```
select * from preferences p left outer join (select * from preferencesdisplay where user_id='XXXX') display on ap.pref_id=display.pref_id;
```

The JPA entity *PREFERENCES* has a OneToMany relationship to *PREFERENCESDISPLAY*.  I want to get all the *PREFERENCES* whether or not there is a *PREFERENCESDISPLAY* reference.

Comment: the JPA provider is Toplink if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hibernate you can use "with":

```
select ... from Preferences p left join p.displays d  with  d.user.id = 100
```

But in JPA I have never seen such possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Does that SQL even work?

It would help if you showed your Entities, however if you have everything correctly mapped it should be this easy:

```
select p from Preferences p left join p.preferencesDisplays pd with pd.userId =XXXX
```

or if with isn't supported by TopLink

```
select p from Preferences p left join p.preferencesDisplays pd
where pd IS NULL or pd.userId = XXXX
```

Comment: The idea is that I only want to do a left outer join on all the preferencesDisplays that have userid=xxxx

Comment: The UserID field is on the PreferenceDisplay entity.