# JPA left join query

Tags: jpa

Given the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `access_time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_hash` (`name_hash`),
  KEY `access_time` (`access_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `x_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`access_time`) REFERENCES `update_time` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `y` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `update_time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reason` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `x` (`x`,`update_time`),
  KEY `reason` (`reason`),
  KEY `update_time` (`update_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `y_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reason`) REFERENCES `reason` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `y_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`x`) REFERENCES `x` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `y_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`update_time`) REFERENCES `update_time` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used NetBeans to create the following JPA classes (X and Y are not the real names, think I did all of the required changes):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X", catalog = "topiclymobile", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name_hash"})})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "X.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM X t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "X.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM X t WHERE t.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "X.findByNameHash", query = "SELECT t FROM X t WHERE t.nameHash = :nameHash"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "X.findByName", query = "SELECT t FROM X t WHERE t.name = :name")})
public class X implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name_hash", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String nameHash;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 1024)
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "access_time", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private UpdateTime accessTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "X")
    private List<Y> YList;

    public X() {
    }

    public X(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public X(Long id, String nameHash, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nameHash = nameHash;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNameHash() {
        return nameHash;
    }

    public void setNameHash(String nameHash) {
        this.nameHash = nameHash;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UpdateTime getAccessTime() {
        return accessTime;
    }

    public void setAccessTime(UpdateTime accessTime) {
        this.accessTime = accessTime;
    }

    public List<Y> getYList() {
        return YList;
    }

    public void setYList(List<Y> YList) {
        this.YList = YList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.nameHash != null ? this.nameHash.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final X other = (X) obj;
        if ((this.nameHash == null) ? (other.nameHash != null) : !this.nameHash.equals(other.nameHash)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "Y", catalog = "topiclymobile", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"X", "update_time"})})
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Y.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Y t"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Y.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM Y t WHERE t.id = :id")})
public class Y implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "reason", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Reason reason;

    @JoinColumn(name = "X", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private X X;

    @JoinColumn(name = "update_time", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private UpdateTime updateTime;

    public Y() {
    }

    public Y(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Reason getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(Reason reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public X getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public void setX(X X) {
        this.X = X;
    }

    public UpdateTime getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(UpdateTime updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 13 * hash + (this.X != null ? this.X.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 13 * hash + (this.updateTime != null ? this.updateTime.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Y other = (Y) obj;
        if (this.X != other.X && (this.X == null || !this.X.equals(other.X))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.updateTime != other.updateTime && (this.updateTime == null || !this.updateTime.equals(other.updateTime))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I am after is all of the cases that "x" does not have a corresponding "y" for a given time (access_time and update_time are the same thing).

This SQL query works, I just cannot seem to translate it into an JPA query:

```
SELECT t.id FROM x t LEFT JOIN y r ON t.id = r.x WHERE r.x IS NULL AND t.access_time = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be helpful to see your entity classes to construct the actual query, but JPA does support `LEFT JOIN`s. [This blog post](http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/11/20/performing-a-left-outer-join-using-jpql-and-jpa/) has a full example, as does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395021/jpa-nested-select-left-outer-join), but something like

```
SELECT x FROM X x LEFT JOIN x.y ...
```

I'm not sure what the rest of the query should be as what you posted does not look like valid SQL (you have `WHERE r.x IS NULL`, but the schema given defines x on table y as `NOT NULL`; similarly, having `WHERE r.x IS NULL` ought to make your left join match nothing, since `t.id = r.x` would always evaluate to `NULL`).

**EDIT:** I'm still confused as to how your sample SQL is a valid query, but something like this seems like it ought to translate into the SQL you provided:

```
SELECT x FROM X x LEFT JOIN x.yList y where y.x IS NULL and x.accessTime = :accessTime
```

Where the `:accessTime` parameter is the value of `entityManager.getReference(UpdateTime.class, 1)`.

Again, though, the `FROM x LEFT JOIN y on x.id = y.x WHERE y.x IS NULL` should match precisely no rows in Y, whereas (since it's a `LEFT JOIN`), it will include all the rows in X. In other words, I think your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT x.id FROM X where x.access_time = 1
```

Which would be this in JPA:

```
SELECT x FROM X x where x.accessTime = :accessTime
```

Comment: the SQL works in mysql... admittedly I didn't write it to start with (databases are not really my thing).  Off to try what you posted.