# How can I JOIN multiple table columns in jpa and jpql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I'm new with JPA and JPQL. I'm trying to query a database grab rows from a table that contains mostly index's of the names contained in other tables.

This is the query in mysql that I'm trying to recreate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as PieceCount, 
                  shifttimes.shiftid as ShiftId, 
                  specienames.NameText as SpecieName, 
                  gradenames.NameText as Grade, 
                  DryerNum, 
                  CreatedLocal      
                  from sheets, shifttimes, specienames, gradenames  
                  WHERE sheets.ShiftIndex = shifttimes.ShiftIndex AND 
                  sheets.SpecieNameIndex = specienames.NameIndex AND
                  sheets.gradenameindex = gradenames.NameIndex AND  
                  CreatedLocal >= '" . $begin . $StartGraveyard  
                  ' AND CreatedLocal < '" . $end . $StartGraveyard 
                  GROUP BY ShiftId, SpecieName, Grade, DryerNum;
```

This is the query I have and as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.createdLocal), 
                g.nameText gName,
                p.nameText pName 
                FROM Sheets s , GradeNames g , SpecieNames p 
                JOIN s.gradeNameIndex gIndex , 
                JOIN s.specieNameIndex pIndex
                 WHERE gIndex = g.nameIndex AND 
               pIndex = p.nameIndex
                 GROUP BY gName , pName
```

This is the Java Glassfish error that I am receiving:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT COUNT(s.createdLocal), g.nameText, p.nameText FROM Sheets s , GradeNames g , SpecieNames p JOIN s.gradeNameIndex gIndex , JOIN s.specieNameIndex pIndex WHERE gIndex = g.nameIndex AND pIndex = p.nameIndex GROUP BY g.nameText , p.nameText]. 
[128, 128] The range variable declaration must be specified.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA left join query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815285/jpa-left-join-query)

Comment: you should better stop using this syntax `FROM Sheets s , GradeNames g , SpecieNames p`. all tables you need should be properly `JOIN`ed by `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, sorry, but this is not an answer but BIG comment...

You should better stop using this syntax `FROM Sheets s , GradeNames g , SpecieNames p`.

All tables you need should be properly `JOIN`ed by `ON` clause.

Any `JOIN` statement should have `ON` clause and should not have `,` any comma at the end.

If I understood your 2nd query correctly it must be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.createdLocal), 
   g.nameText gName,
   p.nameText pName 
FROM Sheets s 
JOIN GradeNames g
ON s.gradeNameIndex  = g.nameIndex 
JOIN SpecieNames p 
ON s.specieNameIndex = p.nameIndex
GROUP BY gName , pName
```